# Trying to get my python functions to work and they are not working correctly

Tags: python

I am not able to get my python functions to work together and do not know why. I am not getting errors but I am getting zeros for my calculations and have included the code below. Any information to fix is appreciated:

```
def main():

# Variables in Float
wallNumber   = 0
widthOfWall  = 0.00 #float
heightOfWall = 0.00
costPerGallonPaint   = 0.00
hours  = 0.00

squareFootage = 0.00

chargeCustomerForPaint = 0.00

wallPaintedSquareFeet = 110 #const square feet of wall to be painted
gallonsOfPaint        = 0.00
roundednumberofPaint  = 0
hourRate              = 25  # const 25 dollars an hour for 100 square feet 
of paint
laborCost             = 0.00
totalCostToCustomer   = 0.00

#####################################
# Information to be provided to user
# Ask the user to enter the width of wall in feet
# Ask the user to enter the height of wall in feet
# Ask the user to to enter the cost per gallon of paint
####################################

costPerGallonPaint = float(input("Enter the cost per gallon of paint: "))
print("You entered  ",costPerGallonPaint)

for wallNumber in range(1,5):
print("Number of wall to be painted ",wallNumber)

widthOfWall = float(input("Enter the width of the wall in feet: "))
print("You entered  ",widthOfWall)

heightOfWall = float(input("Enter the height of the wall in feet: "))
print("You entered  ",heightOfWall)


######################################
#   Calculate square footage for wall to be painted
#   squareFootage = width * height
#   Charge the customer for 1 gallon of piant for every 110 square feet of 
#  wall 
# to be painted
#   Square Footage / wallPaintedSquareFeet
#   gallon is less then 110 square feet charge one gallon
#   more than one gallon then charge  for the amount of gallon
######################################

roundednumberofPaint =int(round(gallonsOfPaint + .5, 0)) #rounds up to the 
next number

def calcsquareFootage(widthOfWall, heightOfWall):
#squareFootage = widthOfWall * heightOfWall
return widthOfWall * heightOfWall

def calcgallonsOfPaint (squareFootage, wallPaintedSquareFeet):
#gallonsOfPaint = squareFootage / wallPaintedSquareFeet
return squareFootage / wallPaintedSquareFeet

def calcchargeCustomerForPaint(costPerGallonPaint, roundednumberofPaint):
return costPerGallonPaint * roundednumberofPaint
#chargeCustomerForPaint = costPerGallonPaint * roundednumberofPaint

print("Charge customer = %.02f"%calcchargeCustomerForPaint    
(costPerGallonPaint, roundednumberofPaint))

def calclaborCost(gallonsOfPaint, hourRate):
return gallonsOfPaint * hourRate

print("Cost of labor is = %.02f"%calclaborCost(gallonsOfPaint, hourRate))


#########################
#   total cost to customer
#########################

totalCostToCustomer = chargeCustomerForPaint + laborCost
print ("Total cost to customer is %.02f"%totalCostToCustomer)
```

Comment: Please atleast fix you indentation . Also you would need to try to debug it a bit yourself, to find out exactly what is returning 0, and what it was supposed to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your *specific* problem is that all your cost calculations are base on `gallonsOfPaint`, which is initialised to zero and *never changed.* You have a line of code that looks like it's intended to change it, but it appears to be commented out.

> As an aside, I'm not sure in which universe a labour cost would be calculated by multiply the hourly rate by the number of gallons of paint, but I'm sure that's something you'll get round to fixing at some point :-)

Comment: Thanks that did answer my question. It is a homework assignment in Python and a poorly written one. That is why the math does not exactly make sense. It would not work in anything real world. Thanks that fixed the issue right away!